# PHP prepare a MySQL query to populate HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have to prepare a query from MySQL table in PHP using a prepared statement in order to build an HTML table of opening hours in multiple languages. The fallback language is English (i.e. *en*) so if no value exists for session language (e.g. *fr*), then it should return the fallback language *en*.

TABLE_A

```
id  | att_id | item_id | lang | row | col | value
1   | 260    | 15      | en   | 0   | 0   | Monday  
2   | 260    | 15      | en   | 0   | 1   | 10:30 - 15:00  
3   | 260    | 15      | en   | 0   | 2   | 18:30 - 24:00  
4   | 260    | 15      | fr   | 0   | 0   | Lundi  
5   | 260    | 15      | fr   | 0   | 1   | 10:30 - 15:00  
6   | 260    | 15      | fr   | 0   | 2   | 18:30 - 24:00  
7   | 260    | 15      | en   | 1   | 0   | Tuesday  
8   | 260    | 15      | en   | 1   | 1   | 10:30 - 15:00  
9   | 260    | 15      | en   | 1   | 2   | 18:30 - 24:00  
10  | 260    | 15      | fr   | 1   | 0   | Mardi  
11  | 260    | 15      | fr   | 1   | 1   | 10:30 - 15:00  
12  | 260    | 15      | fr   | 1   | 2   | 18:30 - 24:00
13  | 260    | 15      | en   | 2   | 0   | Wednesday  
14  | 260    | 15      | en   | 2   | 1   | 10:30 - 15:00  
15  | 260    | 15      | en   | 2   | 2   | 18:30 - 24:00 
16  | 260    | 13      | en   | 0   | 0   | Monday  
17  | 260    | 13      | en   | 0   | 1   | 10:30 - 15:00  
18  | 260    | 13      | en   | 0   | 2   | 18:30 - 24:00
```

*item_id* is the company so I have to pass the company ID, in this case 15, and *att_id* is the field so I have to pass *260*.

For fallback language I can use a *COALESCE* with a JOIN on the same table.

It works but returns double results and NOT one. With *COALESCE* it should  return the first result NOT NULL.

This is the select:

```
SELECT 
        TABLE_A.item_id, TABLE_A.row, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_A.col) AS col, TABLE_A.value,

        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT 
                    TABLE_A.value FROM TABLE_A 
                WHERE 
                TABLE_A.item_id = '15' AND 
                TABLE_A.att_id = '260' AND 
                TABLE_A.row = T.row AND 
                TABLE_A.col = T.col AND 
                TABLE_A.langcode = 'fr'
            ),
            (
                SELECT 
                    TABLE_A.value FROM TABLE_A 
                WHERE 
                TABLE_A.item_id = '15' AND 
                TABLE_A.att_id = '260' AND 
                TABLE_A.row = T.row AND 
                TABLE_A.col = T.col AND 
                TABLE_A.langcode = 'en'
            )
        )) AS name

    FROM TABLE_A

    JOIN TABLE_A AS T ON T.id = TABLE_A.id

    WHERE TABLE_A.att_id = '260' AND TABLE_A.item_id = '15' GROUP BY TABLE_A.row
```

If the session language is *fr* this is the result:

```
[{"row":"0","col":"0,0,1,1,2,2","value":"Lundi,Lundi,10:30 - 15:00,10:30 - 15
:00,18:30 - 24:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"1","col":"0,0,1,1,2,2","value":"Mardi,Mardi,10
:30 - 15:00,10:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"2","col":"0,0,1,1,2,2","value":"Wednesday,
Wednesday,10:30 - 15:00,10:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00,18:30 - 24:00"}]
```

If the session language is *en* this is the result:

```
[{"row":"0","col":"0,0,1,1,2,2","value":"Monday,Monday,10:30 - 15:00,10:30 - 15
:00,18:30 - 24:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"1","col":"0,0,1,1,2,2","value":"Tuesday,Tuesday,10
:30 - 15:00,10:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"2","col":"0,0,1,1,2,2","value":"Wednesday,
Wednesday,10:30 - 15:00,10:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00,18:30 - 24:00"}]
```

What should return:

If the session language is *fr*:

```
[{"row":"0","col":"0,1,2","value":"Lundi,10:30 - 15
:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"1","col":"0,1,2","value":"Mardi,10
:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"2","col":"0,1,2","value":"
Wednesday,10:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00"}]
```

If the session language is *en*:

```
[{"row":"0","col":"0,1,2","value":"Monday,10:30 - 15
:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"1","col":"0,1,2","value":"Tuesday,10
:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00"},{"row":"2","col":"0,1,2","value":"
Wednesday,10:30 - 15:00,18:30 - 24:00"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given that you parse the array in php anyaway, I just don't understand why you bother with group_concat

Comment: @Strawberry or how you want to group the row value ? with this array it's fast to build the html table using explode maybe I am in wrong or there are other solution cleaner

Comment: you should apply a condition on the language in your SQL by binding to the language of the session (or `en` if none defined). Provide your PHP code that is relevant for preparing the SQL statement and binding the arguments.

Comment: @trincot according the session language is affected only the value and the condition I passed in the COALESCE.

Comment: I see, it is hard to understand which are the dynamic argument values, and which are literals in your SQL. It would have been easier if you have provided the SQL with the placeholders and the PHP code that binds the variables. I have answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting all language records, only select the English ones, and outer join the ones for the selected language. Then use `coalesce` to first use the value from the second table, and then (as fallback), the from the first:

```
SELECT      a.item_id, 
            a.row, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(a.col) AS col, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(b.value, a.value)) AS name
FROM        TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN   TABLE_A b 
         ON a.item_id = b.item_id
        AND a.att_id = b.att_id
        AND a.row = b.row
        AND a.col = b.col
        AND b.langcode = ?
WHERE       a.langcode = 'en'
        AND a.att_id = ? 
        AND a.item_id = ? 
GROUP BY    a.row
```